# Is it possible to reverse engineer C# code in Rational Rose?

Tags: c#, uml, sequence-diagram, rational-rose

I am using Rational Rose Enterprise Edition 7.0. It does not give options for importing C# code for reverse engineering the design. Any add ins can be downloaded?

Or I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional (**not** Ultimate edition). Is there an easier way to generate the sequence / collaboration diagrams from the code?

Comment: Lookig here http://m.ibm.com/http/www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/ seems that it suports VS

Comment: Last time I tried it was called "Rational Rose XDE" that worked for C#  couple of years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) will help to generate the class diagrams and API documentation. It also has options to generate Collaboration and other UML diagrams using Graphviz dot.

Comment: The API documentation was a plus. Thanks a lot. It is very easy to get it generated. Just point and follow the wizard http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/doxywizard_usage.html